# How space is interpreted in the format of C scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

I would like to know how space is interpreted in the format of C scanf.

for example, when I write:

```
scanf("%d ",&c);
```

the value read from the keyboard is not directly assigned to the variable `c`.

And if I write:

```
while(c != 0){
    scanf("%d  ",&c);
    printf("c = %d\n", c);
}
```

I have to enter `0` twice to exit the `while` loop.

Can someone explain this behaviour?

Thanks.

Comment: `while (c == 0)` seems the right test, not `while(c != 0)`.

Comment: @RSahu I don't think so as the OP mentions "*I have to enter 0 twice to \*exit\* the `while` loop.*"

Comment: @CoolGuy, perhaps. It's unclear what `c` has been initialized to.

Comment: @RSahu c is initialized to 1.

Comment: @watou, in that case, your test is good :)

Answer (score 4):

I assume `c` is declared as:

```
int c;
```

When you have a `scanf` line

```
scanf("%d  ",&c);
```

the program will read into `c` the first non-whitespace characters that represent an `int`. It will skip all the whitespaces before the first non-whitespace character. That addresses the `%d` part of the format string. Then, it processes the whitespace part of the format string. It will wait to read all the whitespace characters from the stream that follow the last character that was processed to read into `c`. It will stop reading only when it encounters a subsequent non-whitespace character. The first non-whitespace character can be anything. It doesn't have to be a digit/number.

If you enter `10k` as input, it will stop right away after reading `10`. `k` will still be left in the input stream.

Answer (score 1):

`"  "` requires `scanf("%d  ",&c);` to consume *all* white-space after an integer has been scanned.

Use input is line buffered.  `scanf()` receives nothing until a `'\n'` or `EOF` is occurs.

---

Example

1. User types: <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> which sends `" 123\n"` to `stdin`.
2. `scanf("%d"` consumes the `" 123"` scans the `'\n'` and seeing it is not a digit, "ungets" and puts it back into `stdin`.
3. `scanf(" "` consumes the white-spaces `'\n'` and *waits* for more input to examine.
4. User types: <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> which sends `" 456\n"` to `stdin`.
5. `scanf(` continues step 3: scans the `' '`, consumes it, scans the `'4'`, and seeing it is not a white-space, "ungets" and puts it back into `stdin`.
6. The second space of the format `scanf(" "` scans the `'4'` ans seeing it is not a white-space, "ungets" and puts it back into `stdin`.
7. Finally first `scanf()` return as it is done.  It retuns a 1 as it successfully scanned the first field.   Notice 2 <kbd>Enter</kbd>s have occurred.
8. The next `scanf("%d"` consumes the `"456"` and continues like step 2 above.

Do not recommend to have a format end in white-space with `scanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

[N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 7.19.6.2 The fscanf function

> A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the
>   first non-white-space character (which remains unread), or until no more characters can
>   be read.

N1256 7.19.6.4 The scanf function

> 2 The scanf function is equivalent to fscanf with the argument stdin interposed
>   before the arguments to scanf.